# Unhappy about one's appearance?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a single word that means "unhappy about one's appearance"?

E.g., [Anne of Green Gables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anne_of_Green_Gables) was very unhappy about her hair and never missed an opportunity to try to dye it.

Comment: Perhaps "self-critical," although that could apply to more than just appearance.

Comment: A quick glimpse at a list of "diseases of the soul" (coined by Ursula Le Guin) doesn't have anything specific to appearance. But *anguish* is the general thing, I think.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I think "anguish" is too strong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***self-conscious***, according to [vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/self-conscious)

> Being self-conscious goes beyond just being aware of yourself — when
>   you're self-conscious, you constantly question the way you appear to
>   others

Expanding on the OP's example:

> Anne is very **self-conscious** about her hair.  She is always trying new
>   shampoos and conditioners and experimenting with new styles.

A person who is **self-conscious** about their weight may or may not be too heavy (or too thin) but they think they are.

Comment: Anne of Green Gables was self-conscious about her hair ...

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to find such a word but try [stress](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stress)

> to feel very worried or anxious about something.

"Anne of Green gables was very stressed about her hair."

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a single-word for it. If it's a disorder, it might be:

[**Body dysmorphic disorder (BDD)**](http://www.nhs.uk/conditions/Body-dysmorphia/pages/introduction.aspx)

> Body dysmorphic disorder (BDD) is an anxiety disorder that causes a person to have a distorted view of how they look and to spend a lot of time worrying about their appearance.

Source: nhs.uk

It also explains the following:

- When does low confidence turn into BDD?
- Who is affected?
- Typical behaviours of someone with BDD
- What causes BDD?
- Getting help
- Treating BDD